# Codeigniter display details from table 1 if equal to specific category in table 2

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this table in my database, let's call it table1 shown below:

[Table 1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwBGhbPaJU_jRUZxemk3TGVqams)

And another table which we'll take as table 2:

[Table 2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwBGhbPaJU_jNGhKRFVTSVM1aXM)

I want to display the contents in table 2 but only the contents that have `category_id` matching `id` in table 2.

How do I code my controller, model and view(just the relevant parts) to achieve this?

Please I'm a newbie when it comes to php and codeigniter. I am using codeigniter 3 by the way

Comment: what did you even try ?

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches for doing it.

1. You can create two separate method in model for retrieving data from both table. Then pass your data to views  & using check data for displaying the right data.
2. You can use a inner join query with table2 for retrieving specific data like this

`join with table2 where table1.category_id = table2.id`

It will be easier & efficient. You will get actual data & pass them to views via controller & display where you want.

Comment: Thank you. I am going to try this.

Comment: Okay so I used this `INNER JOIN WITH categories WHERE products.category_id = categories.id;` but I got an error on `JOIN` saying: Unrecognized statement type. (near "INNER JOIN" at position 0). I put this into phpmyadmin sql code section.

Answer (score 0):

in model you can use this method.

```
public function your_method_name()
 { $sql = $this->db->query('SELECT * from table1, table2 where table1.id =table2.id);
   return $sql->result();
 }
```

in your controller you can use this method.

```
 public function your_method_name(){
  $this->load->your_model; //to load your model
  $data['show'] = $this->your_model->your_method_name;
  $this->load->view('your_view',$data);
 }
```

and you can write in your view with foreach. example like this.

```
 <?php foreach($show as $key){
echo $key->your_column_name;
 ?>
```

well, it's done. I hope this will solve your problems.

Comment: It says `show` is undefined. Thanks for helping out :) Is there perhaps an error on the third line of the controller?

Comment: @RobinOlisa undifined what? Undifined varriable $show?

Comment: @RobinOlisa can you share how you try sir? If undifined varriable $show you just can check at your $data give an array example $data['show']. Or you can write $data = array('show'=>$this->your_model->your_method_name). Cause the show varriable for call your data. And you can write the $show with the foreac in tye view.

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Example extends CI_Controller
{ 
    public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->load->model('Example_model');
    }

    public function index(){
      $data['result'] = $this->Example_model->get_data();
      $this->load->view('layout',$data);
    }
}
```

Model:

```
class Example_model extends CI_Model {

   function __construct() 
   {   
       parent::__construct();
       $this->load->database('default',TRUE);           
   }

   public function get_data(){
      $this->db->join('tbale1','table.category_id=table2.id');
      return $this->db->get('table2')->result();
   }
}
```

View:

```
 <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php
           foreach($result as $key => $value){
        ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $value->category_id; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Okay I tried it but I got an error saying result is undefined.